# Convert currency dataframe column to float

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to convert a currency column in my DataFrame to float values so I can compute some stats.
Here's how the column looks like:

```
10.785,177
10.783,554
10.781,931
10.782,094
10.780,843
656,530
```

The result should be:

```
10785.177
10783.554
10781.931
10782.094
10780.843
656.530
```

I was trying to do something with regex but I don't know a lot about it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.apply()` like this:

```
df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(".", "").replace(",",".")).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove thousands separators (`.`), [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) decimal separators (`,`) with `.`, and then you can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pd.yuanpy.top/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
>>> df['col'].str.replace('.', '', regex=False).str.replace(',', '.', regex=False)\
...          .transform(pd.to_numeric)
0    10785.177
1    10783.554
2    10781.931
3    10782.094
4    10780.843
5      656.530
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Just a question, is there a way to do this inplace or do I have to add the Series to the dataframe manually?

Comment: You can always reassign it into the same column `df['col'] = df['col'].str...`

Comment: No worries @DaviMagalhães. Good luck with the rest of your code